# Stream a folder of music to a Squeezebox without installing Slimserver?

Tags: music, streaming, squeezebox

I've got a folder of MP3s and I'm near a friend's Squeezebox, which is connected to mysqueezebox.com.

Is there a quick way I can play these MP3s on the Squeezebox without installing Slimserver? Something like a shell one-liner that creates an `.m3u` file and runs an HTTP server, maybe passing the URL to that server to the Squeezebox UI somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could install a media streamer, e.g. [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/), then connect to that stream on the Squeezebox.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to share your MP3s, or stream them, you can connect an MP3 player to the "line in" jack on the back of the SB,  That way, you can take them with you when you leave for the day.